# I want to move one div below the container as the page resizes, How can I do that?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following structure. https://i.stack.imgur.com/l59Zx.png {Link to the Image}

I want to move the sidebar in the bottom on resizing the window but I can't figureout a way to do it.

Here are some pieces of my code

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
<div id="sidebar">.........</div>
<div class="content box">......</div>
</div>

CSS

.contentWrapper{
position: relative;
width:980px;
padding:91px 0 0 0;
margin:0 auto
}

#sidebar {
position: absolute;
top:100px; bottom:-100px; right:0;
width:200px;
background:#000;
}

.contentBox{
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#cc000000,endColorstr=#cc000000); /* IE */
padding:30px 0;
margin:0 auto;
font-family:'Abel';
font-size:24px;
color:#fff;
text-align:center
}
```

Comment: add a css media query for it.

Comment: Why do you require `position: absolute`? If you don't need it, don't use it. Many layouts break because of that property when you don't actually need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you this:

```
@media max-width(768px){ 
  #sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is using `@media` queries.

Use this code at the bottom of your rest of the CSS code.

```
@media (max-width: 768px){  /* mention the width here in px for which you want the sidebar to move down */
  #sidebar {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Read up: [CSS media queries - Web developer guide | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

You could try with some `media queries` [more info here on w3s](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

In your CSS, something along the lines of

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #sidebar{
   //css here
  }
}
```